# Handling multiple layers of Data in DataTables?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I want to use DataTables to store multiple "layers" of data.
Some Procedure computes means, absolute values and percentages for me. Theese three layers have excactly identical ordered rows and columns, but the values change.
When I delete or insert a row, similar operations must be made to the other two tables as well. Has somebody a good Idea?

Further explanation:

```
 Dim absTable as DataTable
 Dim meanTable as DataTable
 Dim percTable as DataTable
 abstable.rows(2).delete
```

How can I guarantee, that this operation is executed on the other two tables as well?

Comment: Why not store them all in the same table by simply adding a separate column for each type of calculation result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want use a `DataSet` instead of multiple `DataTable`. Because, in `DataSet`, you can manipulate multiple `DataTable` using the `.Tables(Index|TableName)` property witch assure you to do operations on the right table. You need an higher hierarchical object to do what you want.

So if you want to delete a row in all tables, just loop on the desired tables and call the `delete` method:

```
Dim aDataSet as New DataSet 
Dim absTable as New DataTable 
Dim meanTable as New DataTable 
Dim percTable as New DataTable

aTable.Tables.Add(absTable) aTable.Tables.Add(meanTable) aTable.Tables.Add(percTable)

For each table as DataTable in aDataSet.Tables
    table.rows(2).delete 
Next
```

You can also have cross Tables references to ensure or manipulate or do whatever you want on it.

```
aDataSet.Tables(0) = aDataSet.Tables(1) 'only if the talbes 0 and 1 have same columns
```

Hope this is what you asked for.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx for more details on DatsSet.

Comment: Thanks, that looks very promising.